# hibernateTemplate.delete() delete the proper entity and the FK in relationated table

Tags: hibernate-mapping

I have two tables: "Libros" and "Autores". The relationship is many-to-many.

When I delete an entry from Libros (HibernateTemplate.delete(libro)) this operation delete the record on the intermediate table "Libros_autores" (which is right). But its delete a record on Autores table which is not right for me.

In the mapping file changed the cascade from "all" to "save-update" but it fails because there is an id on table libros_autores which is FK from Libros. So, if Libros record is deleted the row in libros_autores have to be deleted as well to avoid contraints problems (which is absolutly logic for me).

Then my problem is: If I delete a record on table Libros its delete on table autores as well and i only want to be deleted on tables: Libros and libros_autores.

Mapping files are:

Libro.hbm.xml

```
<class name="app.modelo.Libro" table="libros">

        <id name="isbn" column="ISBN" type="string" length="20">
                 <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
     <set name="autores" table="autores_libros" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
                <key column="ISBN"/>
                <many-to-many column="ID_AUTOR" class="app.modelo.Autor"/>
            </set>
</class>
```

Autor.hbm.xml

```
  <class name="app.modelo.Autor" table="autores">

        <id name="id" column="ID_AUTOR" type="integer" length="20">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
    <set name="libros" table="autores_libros" cascade="all">
        <key column="ID_AUTOR"/>
        <many-to-many column="ISBN" class="app.modelo.Libro"/>
    </set>
  </class>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you should not user cascade="all". I think it means it will really exclude the autor as you exclude the libro. I understand the relationship will be implicity deleted anyway.

See this from the book "Hibernate in Action":

> We’ve chosen cascade="save-update" for both ends of the collection; this isn’t unreasonable. On the other hand, cascade="all", cascade="delete", and cas-cade="all-delete-orphans" aren’t meaningful for many-to-many associations, since an instance with potentially many parents shouldn’t be deleted when just one parent is deleted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I ve created a hbm.xml file (AutorLibro. Which is the given name in the hbm.xml file for Autor and Libro in the many-to-many relationship). I ve created the class AutorLibro, set the attributes and then delete it before delete Libro. And it works perfectly